# MonoTouch.Dialog Autorotate

Tags: xamarin.ios, rotation, autorotate, monotouch.dialog

I can't seem to get the MonoTouch.Dialog to rotate.  In my constructor, I set Autorotate = true.  I also added all orientations in the supported orientations section of info.plist.  I also overrode the ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method to return true.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

When using a default template from MonoDevelop then only setting `Autorotate` to `true` on **every** `DialogViewController` (not just the main one) should be enough.

E.g. this is what [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) does and rotation works without any issue. You might want to check and compare its code with your own code.